# mysql inner join with group by

Tags: mysql, group-by, aggregate

I am using the following query to get correct results for each batch. For example if I would to like to see the total of invoice for batch 2010...

```
SELECT COALESCE(sum(i.amount),0) AS amount, 
    COALESCE(sum(i.discount),0) AS discount,
    COALESCE(sum(i.amount) - sum(i.discount),0) AS netpay,
    b.name AS batch
FROM fm_batches b
    INNER JOIN fm_invoices i
    LEFT JOIN fm_students s ON i.student_id = s.id
GROUP BY b.name
```

And its outputting the following results...

```
| amount | discount | netpay   | batch | 
+--------+----------+----------+-------+
| 2500   | 500      | 2000     | 2011  |
+--------+----------+----------+-------+
| 2500   | 500      | 2000     | 2010  |
+--------+----------+----------+-------+
| 2500   | 500      | 2000     | 2009  |
+--------+----------+----------+-------+
| 2500   | 500      | 2000     | 2008  |
+--------+----------+----------+-------+
```

I am sure that I am doing something wrong in my query as its giving the wrong results. It should return 0 if nothing found for batch 2010.  thanks.

Comment: What is your relationship between invoices and batches... is there a batch column on invoices table?

Comment: There is no ON clause for the invoices JOIN. What's the relationship between invoices and batches/subscriptions?

Comment: @DRapp no i don't have batch column on invoices table but i have that in subscribers table, so tables would be subscribers, invoices and batches

Comment: @Galz see my above comment, batch is related to subscriber table and subscriber is related to invoices using subs_id

Comment: See my answer now. I made some edits to it. I also had to guess the relationship between subscribers and batches (`s.bacth_id = b.id`) - you can correct it as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you need something like:

```
SELECT COALESCE(sum(i.amount),0) AS amount, 
    COALESCE(sum(i.discount),0) AS discount, 
    COALESCE(sum(i.amount)-sum(i.discount),0) AS netpay, 
    b.name AS batch 
FROM batches b 
LEFT JOIN subscribers s on s.bacth_id = b.id
LEFT JOIN invoices i on i.subs_id = s.id
GROUP BY b.name
```

(guessing the relationship between subscribers and batches).

Comment: i don't have batch_id on invoices table, its on subscribers table, so batch is related to subscribers and subscribers is related to invoices.

Comment: i think it would work fine, i will test it and will mark this answer, thanks for help.